# Removing an android app making troubles from Recovery mode

Tags: boot

I have "Call Recorder" app installed on my android phone and changed the recording option to Kernel and choose another device name. It caused phone to stop its touch working and etc after auto-running this app when rebooting.... Now what can I do to solve this problem by preventing this app of running in start-up? Maybe these ways are helpful: 1- To remove app's files installed on storage from the file manager of recovery mode. but which folder or files? 2- Maybe using one of wipe options in recovery. but which one can help me? 3- Or every way else...

Thanks for your help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try rebooting in safe mode. After getting the power menu, hold down on `power off` and choose `reboot in safe mode`.

You could also use adb commands found in this [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12949609/adb-shell-command-to-make-android-package-uninstall-dialog-appear).

If you don't feel comfortable with that, you may have to do a factory reset.